# get the data for the previous day in Python

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.7

I am very much new to `Python` and need to extract previous day data from `RESTAPI` and in my `RESTAPI` request i need to provide `QueryStartDate` and `QueryEndDate`. Till now for testing i am providing the previous day date(sysdate-1) manually. But now as i wanted to automated the process, i want to apply Python function to always get the previous date so that i can extract the whole day data from previous day.

I am using UTC time zone so this part `T12:00:00.000Z` i need to keep as it is otherwise my request to `RESTAPI` will not run. So i just need to change date part.

```
"QueryStartDate": "2021-09-02T12:00:00.000Z"
"QueryEndDate": "2021-09-02T12:10:00.000Z"
```

I tried to apply `datetime.now() - timedelta(1)` function to get previous day date but not sure due to syntax issue the RESTAPI request is throwing an error.

Comment: You mean if today is Sep 3, 2021, you want to have the strings `"2021-09-02T00:00:00.000+0000"` and `"2021-09-02T23:59:59.999+0000"`? Or is it always fixed to `T12:00:00.000Z` and `T12:10:00.000Z`?

Comment: yes correct the problem is here with double quotes also which we have to be careful...and i need previous date "2021-09-02T23:59:59.999+0000" ...its not fixed T12:00:00.000Z and T12:10:00.000Z because in querystartdate we need to start from 00 and queryenddate it should be 24 so that i can get whole day data from previous date

Comment: Ok understood. I added an answer, could you check if it satisfies what you need?

Comment: yes i am testing it thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the string value of the previous day in the format of either:

- Format 1: `"2021-09-02T00:00:00.000000+0000"`
- Format 2: `"2021-09-02T00:00:00.000000Z"`

Which ranges from the start time `00:00:00.000000` to the end time `23:59:59.999999`, you can use [datetime.strftime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) along with the [time.min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.min) and [time.max](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.max):

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta, timezone

yesterday_dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(days=1)
yesterday_start_dt = datetime.combine(yesterday_dt, time.min, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
yesterday_end_dt = datetime.combine(yesterday_dt, time.max, tzinfo=timezone.utc)

format1 = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"
format2 = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"

queryStartDate_format1 = yesterday_start_dt.strftime(format1)
queryEndDate_format1 = yesterday_end_dt.strftime(format1)
print("Format 1:")
print(queryStartDate_format1)
print(queryEndDate_format1)

queryStartDate_format2 = yesterday_start_dt.strftime(format2)
queryEndDate_format2 = yesterday_end_dt.strftime(format2)
print("Format 2:")
print(queryStartDate_format2)
print(queryEndDate_format2)
```

**Output**

```
Format 1:
2021-09-02T00:00:00.000000+0000
2021-09-02T23:59:59.999999+0000
Format 2:
2021-09-02T00:00:00.000000Z
2021-09-02T23:59:59.999999Z
```

---

**Update**

Here is a version if the import is based on the root `datetime`.

```
import datetime

yesterday_dt = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc) - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
yesterday_start_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(yesterday_dt, datetime.time.min, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
yesterday_end_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(yesterday_dt, datetime.time.max, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

format1 = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z"
format2 = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ"

queryStartDate_format1 = yesterday_start_dt.strftime(format1)
queryEndDate_format1 = yesterday_end_dt.strftime(format1)
print("Format 1:")
print(queryStartDate_format1)
print(queryEndDate_format1)

queryStartDate_format2 = yesterday_start_dt.strftime(format2)
queryEndDate_format2 = yesterday_end_dt.strftime(format2)
print("Format 2:")
print(queryStartDate_format2)
print(queryEndDate_format2)
```

Comment: i am getting error AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'

Comment: I suppose your import is just `import datetime`. Try changing it to `from datetime import datetime`.

Comment: yes i did the same from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta, timezone and getting error now AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'timezone'......actually previously in my code i also have t = datetime.datetime.now()

Comment: It's actually in the answer. Just use this whole import `from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta, timezone`.

Comment: yes i did the same...i think the problem is in my code i also used t = datetime.datetime.now() where its creating problem now after the new import... i have now two imports .......from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta, timezone
and import datetime---

Comment: Ahh ok. In that case, I assume all your current code is based on `import datetime` (Python made it confusing with the same name ^_^). For cases such as your `datetime.datetime.now()`, it would just be `datetime.now()` if using the import I made.

Comment: ohh but then i am getting error as :    yesterday_dt = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(days=1)
AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'now'.....wow its breaking my code other parts also:   line 151, in <module>
    time.sleep(30)
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.time' has no attribute 'sleep'

Comment: Check my updated answer. It would work with your `import datetime`. To verify that it is working, see this sample run I made https://paiza.io/projects/e/oK1Hc92D8mrRFAepw45nHw?theme=twilight

Comment: To avoid confusion, don't mix these 2 imports: `import datetime` and `from datetime import datetime`. Just use one of them.

Comment: one question here ...actually if i just need to check the previous day date between 7am till 23:00 how to make this change in this logic ?

Comment: You can just use [datetime.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) to change the time part of `yesterday_dt`. Something like `yesterday_start_dt = yesterday_dt.replace(hour=7, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)`

Comment: sorry i tried here but still i am getting data before 7am also :               "QueryStartDate":  yesterday_dt.replace(hour=7, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0).strftime(format2),
            "QueryEndDate": yesterday_dt.replace(hour=23, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0).strftime(format2),

Comment: Check the API side. I tried that exact code you pasted and it worked. See https://paiza.io/projects/e/lFvPWOJi-m2davHaVrRulw?theme=twilight where as you can see, today is 2021-09-17, and in the prints you would correctly see `{'QueryStartDate': '2021-09-16T07:00:00.000000Z', 'QueryEndDate': '2021-09-16T23:00:00.000000Z'}`

Comment: thanks i will check

Answer (score 1):

Use those line of code may be help you to find previous day

```
import datetime
Previous_Date = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
print (Previous_Date)
```

If your using UTC timezone then try:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
todayUTC = datetime.now(timezone.utc).date()
yesterdayUTC = today - timedelta(1)
print(todayUTC, yesterdayUTC)
```

Comment: but i am using UTC time zone and this part is very important T12:00:00.000Z otherwise my request to REST API will not run... i have updated my question accordingly..

Comment: sorry can you please tell me how do i use this in Querystartdate and Queryenddate ?

Comment: Just put todayUTC variable as Querystartdate and yesterdayUTC variable as Queryenddate.

Comment: what about double quotes ?

Comment: You're storing String right, so it's simple. todayUTC and yestardayUTC both type String. don't need to worry about that.